# How to re-render all my react clients every time that changes are made in my database?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, render

I have a client application created with create-react-app and server on nodejs with MySQL as database. What is the best way to render changes in my database on all react clients?

Comment: For realtime, you might wanna consider hooking the changes in the database with a websocket client and connect it to the client.

Comment: How would React know if the database has been updated? Do you post things to your database from the same react app or from any 3rd party application ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is more related to how to get the data than to the react application by itself.

There are multiple options:

- **Real Time Database:** You have databases like firebase which help you to work with this. (Not applicable for you because you have your NodeJS application with MySQL)
- **Sockets:** It's the way how the server notify to all the clients when the data has a change. The easiest implementation would be with socket.io (Definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API - Tool: https://socket.io/)
- **Polling:** It's the one with the worst performance but it's the easiest way to implement. Basically, you can set one `setInterval` (over `setTimeout` and get the information every X time)

You can read a little more about the comparison in: https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9